# Security Management for dynamicly loaded code

Tags: java, security, class, dynamic, securitymanager

I'm currently working on a client/server application that supports dynamicly loaded classes.

These classes are plugins which should not be able to access certain methods.

My first idea was a SecurityManager that checked class names in the stacktrace but that does not seem to be the ideal way to approache this.

How would one employ such restrictions to specific classes?

Is there a (realisable) way to read every referenced class from class file content?

Comment: the "certain methods" should have appropriate access modifiers. If a method is declared public, it will be accessible to all other classes who can instantiate an object and call methods. If you are implementing these "certain methods" yourself, then using appropriate methods of securitymanager may be a good idea.

Comment: Utilizing [AccessController](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html) is a pretty standard Java way of handling this use case.

Comment: It's difficult. Shouldn't be, but it is.

Comment: @Usman: that is not an option.

Comment: @Perception: as far as I can see Privileges are checkt dependent on the current Thread. Is there another way then creating an new Thread for each plugin?